# Gradle Build Distribution Releas

Tags: java, gradle

I'm a Gradle newbie attempting to build a project: https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban

My problem is that the build/release always builds azkaban-*-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip even though the code release is currently 3.43.0. The 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT ends up in the UI and makes it near impossible to detect which version I'm actually running.

```
# ls azkaban-web-server/build/distributions/
azkaban-web-server-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
azkaban-web-server-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

I've tried adding -PprojVersion to GRADLE_OPTS to no avail. How can I get version built to match the actual code version?